# What's the best way to initiate a UI update after n seconds have elapsed?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

My C# WinForms UI has some parameters that the user can adjust using sliders.  Many parts of the UI can interactively update based on the slider values.  However, some parts require a longer calculation that requires some overhead to set up.  I would like to only initiate this update process once the user has stopped moving the sliders for, say, 2 seconds.  What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Timer control that resets the UI if any anything has changes after 2 seconds.

The timer would also check a variable that is flagged after every change, so only when the flag has not changes and timer times out, the UI is upated.

Answer (score 2):

The [Reactive Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) would be perfect for that. If you have C# 3.5, you could use it.

```
Observable.FromEvent<ScrollEventArgs>(vScrollBar1, "Scroll")
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)) // Wait for two second alter all Scroll event ended
    .ObserveOnWindowsForms() // Make the lambda expression run on the UI thread
    .Subscribe(
        e =>
        {
            // Update your stuff
            labelControl1.Text = e.EventArgs.NewValue.ToString();
        });
```

You can get rid of the `ObserveOnWindowsForms` call if you don't want to make your UI to hang while running the lamda, but make sure that you properly access your UI component to avoid cross-threading exception.

Comment: Neat. I was just compiling my list of things to look at over the holidays - I'd forgotten I wanted to learn the Rx framework and this reminded me. Thanks.

Comment: I like this solution even though fluent programming makes me sad.  The big downer is that it requires the Rx library.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a private instance member referencing a thread timer. When the timer hits 2 seconds, the event containing the calculations would fire. All sliders would have an change listener that would set the timer to 0 and start the timer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this timer:  [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx).  Why?  It executes on the UI thread meaning you don't have to use InvokeRequired or BeginInvoke to execute your UI updating code on the UI thread.